# Select element in matrix with index from other matrix

Tags: r, indexing

I am trying to select an element from matrix z with an index from matrix y. When indexing it like this `z[1,y[1,1]]` it gives another value than when indexing it like this `z[1,15]` (with `y[1,1] = 15`). How come?

```
> z[1,y[1,1]]

[1] 15

> y[1,1]

[1] 15

> z[1,15]
   6/09/2021
1:         2
```

Comment: Can you provide your matrices (or a minimal set of your matrices) using `dput` so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: I am guessing you are working with a data.table objects, not matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to rounding differences. This can happen when you stored a vlue into `y[1,1]` which was a result from a calculation.

Let me give you an example when this can happen.

```
mat <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 2)
print(mat)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "a"  "f" 
# [2,] "b"  "g" 
# [3,] "c"  "h" 
# [4,] "d"  "i" 
# [5,] "e"  "j"

ind <- exp(4) / 54.598152 * 2
print(ind)
# [1] 2

print(mat[1, ind]) # Extracts the value from the first column.
# [1] "a"

print(mat[1, round(ind)]) # Extracts the value from the second column.
# [1]  "f"
```

Therefore, try using `z[1, round(y[1,1])]` to check if the problem persists.

Comment: Whoever voted this answer down - this is exactely a problem I encountered in the past. Please explain in the comment why this answer is not helpful.

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment not an answer - notice the use of "may be" in your answer. Regarding rounding, it is irrelevant, see `?Extract`, it is already gets converted to an integer `"Numeric values are coerced to integer as by as.integer (and hence truncated towards zero)"`. Lastly, OP's object most likely not a matrix, but a data.table, notice last row `1:`.

Comment: As the OP didn't edit/clarify further, this question cannot have a valid answer.

Comment: I added an example to illustrate the problem. Please consider removing your downvote.